# NSWindow Flip Animation - Like iWork

Tags: cocoa, animation, transition, nswindow, flip

I'm attempting to implement window-flipping identical to that in iWork -

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2338382/Window%20Flipping.mov

However, I can't quite seem to find a straightforward way of doing this. Some tutorials suggest sticking snapshot-images of both sides of the window in a bigger, transparent window and animate those. This might work, but seems a bit hacky, and the sample code is always bloated. Some tutorials suggest using private APIs, and since this app may be MAS-bound, I'd like to avoid that.

How should I go about implementing this? Does anyone have any hints?

#### NSWindow+Flipping

I've rewritten the ancient code linked below into NSWindow+Flipping. You can grab these source files from [my misc. Cocoa collection on GitHub, PCSnippets](https://github.com/pcperini/PCSnippets).

Comment: See it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567190/nswindow-flip-animation-easy-and-universal/24567191#24567191

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using **CoreGraphics framework**. Take a look at this:

```
- (void) flipWithDuration: (float) duration forwards: (BOOL) forwards
{
  CGSTransitionSpec spec;
  CGSTransitionHandle transitionHandle;
  CGSConnection cid = CGSDefaultConnection;

  spec.type = CGSFlip;
  spec.option = 0x80 | (forwards ? 2 : 1);
  spec.wid = [self windowNumber];
  spec.backColor = nil;

  transitionHandle = -1;
  CGSNewTransition (cid, &spec, &transitionHandle);
  CGSInvokeTransition (cid, transitionHandle, duration);
  [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate: 
        [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: duration]];
  CGSReleaseTransition (cid, transitionHandle);
}
```

You can download sample project: [here](http://regmedia.co.uk/2009/08/20/coregraphics_framework_demmo.zip). More info [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/08/21/cocoa_graphics_framework/).

**UPDATE:**

Take a look at [this project](http://brockerhoff.net/src/Flipr.zip). It's actually what You need.

> **About this project:**
>
> This category on `NSWindow` allows you to switch one window for
>   another, using the "flip" animation popularized by Dashboard widgets.
>   This was a nice excuse to learn something about CoreImage and how to
>   use it in Cocoa. The demo app shows how to use it. Scroll to the end
>   to see what's new in this version!
>
> Basically, all you need to do is something like:

```
[someWindow flipToShowWindow:someOtherWindow forward:YES];
```

> However, this code makes some assumptions: — someWindow (the initial
>   window) is already visible on-screen. — someOtherWindow (the final
>   window) is not already visible on-screen. — Both windows can be
>   resized to the same size, and aren't too large or complicated — the
>   latter conditions being less important the faster your CPU/video card
>   is. — The windows won't go away while the animation is running. — The
>   user won't try to click on the animated window or do something while
>   the animation is running.
>
> The implementation is quite straightforward. I move the final to the
>   same position and size as the initial window. I then position a larger
>   transparent window so it covers that frame. I render both window
>   contents into CIImages, hide both windows, and start the animation.
>   Each frame of the animation renders a perspective-distorted image into
>   the transparent window. When the animation is done, I show the final
>   window. Some tricks are used to make this faster; the flipping window
>   is setup only once; the final window is hidden by setting its alpha to
>   0.0, not by ordering it out and later ordering it back in again, for instance.
>
> The main bottleneck is the CoreImage filter, and the first frame
>   always takes much longer to render — 4 or 6 times what it takes for
>   the remaining frames. I suppose this time is spent with setup and
>   downloading to the video card. So I calculate the time this takes and
>   draw a second frame at a stage where the rotation begins to show. The
>   animation begins at this point, but, if those first two frames took
>   too long, I stretch the duration to make sure that at least 5 more
>   frames will get rendered. This will happen with slow hardware or large
>   windows. At the end, I don't render the last frame at all and swap the
>   final window in instead.

Comment: 2 questions: 1, does this use a private API call? 2, when I use this, I get flipping (YAY) but I lose shadows and rounded corners (boo). Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I don't know 100% that this is not using private API, but I think no. Hmm.. yeah it's kind a bug..

Comment: Yeah... even if I _could_ get away with potentially-private API call, I couldn't ship something this visually glitchy. If you dig up a way to clean this up a bit, post it! This is the most promising lead thusfar.

Comment: Any CoreGraphics APIs prefixed with "CGS" are private APIs. The "CG" APIs are the only public ones.

Comment: @JustinBoo when I drop NSWindow_Flipr into my project (as is), the window flips, but _very_ slowly, and, on completion, disappears forever. Any ideas?

Comment: @pcperini maybe Your windows has checked "release when closed" ? what do You mean very slow? very slow - lagging? or very slow - nice, but slow?

Comment: @pcperini I have created new project and test it. So it works well. You're doing something wrong when You get "dissapear forever". And for lagging test I added two big images in each window, but it's working still nice. (Flip speed can be changed here: `#define DURATION (0.75)`). So I think if Your windows is flipping with lag - it depends what is in Your project. Here is my created project for testing: http://www63.zippyshare.com/v/85211094/file.html.

Comment: This works nearly perfectly! The only concern that I have is that the very first flip is slow (smooth, but slow; about 2-3x DURATION). It doesn't seem to be happening in your application, which would suggest mine is my complicated (it is). Is that the problem? Is it resolvable somehow?

Comment: @pcperini Maybe this would be solution for You: If You are getting smooth flip always at first time why not to change duration time to 2-3x quicker for the first time and for other flips use as always? (for example: first time 0.25 and for others flips 0.75).

Comment: Looks like it flips at about 1.5s on the first flip regardless of what DURATION is set to be.

Comment: @pcperini Maybe something is loading in Your code for the first time when flipping. So I will suggest You: 1) Try comment - uncomment (deleting) less code in second window and find what's making this. 2) Try on my example add Your code.

Comment: For whatever reason, duration was getting artificially stretched. I added a `firstRun`-conditional reset on duration: now there's a .25s delay before a smooth and fast flip, the first time only. Certainly worth 200 rep! Thank you!

Comment: No problem Pcperini, I'm glad that helped You.